# Remove an uiimageview from storyboard completely?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, image, uiimageview

I have a table and a cell with a text and image. i want to remove the imageview completely from the cell because the cells are dynamically generated and some have images and some dont.

i have tried:

```
imageview.hidden = true
```

and i also tried:

```
imageview.removeFromSuperview()
```

but those remove the image but not the image view. right now, when there is no image, the image does not show up in the imageview but there is a huge gap below the text with no image because it seems like the imageview is still there. i want to remove the imageview completely so the huge gap is not there for cells with no images.

Comment: Did you subclass `UITableViewCell` or are you using the default cell?

Comment: @Ike10 what do you mean and how can i check and do that?

Comment: A subclass is something you make as a developer to create a custom version of a class that exists. If you don't know what it is, you can learn more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html . You probably did not do this but you may want to consider making a subclass with no imageView when there is no image. You can learn about subclassing `UITableViewCell`s here: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702

Comment: @Ike10 my layout is like this. View>TableView>TableCell>ContentView>UIImageView

Comment: Since you are not making a subclass, I would try setting the `UITableViewCells`s `imageView.image` property to `nil` where you don't want the imageView to show.

Comment: @Ike10 what are some examples of subviews and how can i add them?

Answer (score 0):

It's important that cells were reused. **Don't** remove because you didn't add it back. And if you hide image view, you should show it when this was needed. Like this:

```
if needed {
    imageview.hidden = false 
} else {
    imageview.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: yes that works but the imageview is not completely hidden, it looks like an invisible placeholder... how can i remove that?

Comment: @johnjay22113 What did you used for layout? Auto-Layout?

Comment: @johnjay22113 You should set its width to 0 and reset when reused. You'd better set its image to nil when reused.(override `prepareForReuse()` of `UITableViewCell`)

Answer (score 0):

Using Autolayout you can solve this problem. Dont give fixed height and fixed width. And check content hugging/compression priority of imageview is properly set or not.